# Porque meu onclick em um onload não funciona?

Tags: javascript

Estou utilizando este código porém a partir do `onclick` ele não funciona se eu clicar no elemento "fa-search", porém se eu colar o mesmo JS no console do chrome ele funciona da forma esperada.

Gostaria de saber o porque? Eu imagino que é algo que estivesse relacionado a escopo.

```js
onload = (() => {
    console.log("agua"); 
    document.getElementsByClassName("fa-search")[0].onclick = () =>{
      document.getElementById("fieldSearch").focus();
      console.log("Executou");
    }
})();
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-R5JkiUweZpJjELPWqttAYmYM1P3SNEJRM6ecTQF05pFFtxmCO+Y1CiUhvuDzgSVZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>    
    <aside id="container">
        <header>Encontre um ponto de venda</header>
        <p>Digite o seu CEP, rua, bairro ou cidade</p>
        <div class="search">           
            <input type="text" id="fieldSearch">
            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>            
        </div>

        <div id="proximidade">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <button>5 KM</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button>10 KM</button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button>15 KM</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="block-list">                
            <i class="fas fa-list"></i>
            <span>Lista</span>            
        </div>
    </aside>
</body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Dist/my-styles.css" />
<script src="../Sass/js/mapa.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: [Funciona normalmente](https://jsfiddle.net/kmdaezwx/), acho que você está se confundindo em outra ponto do seu código.

Comment: Como assim fernando, não entendi direto, me desculpe, porque pelo menos na versão do chrome aqui não está funcionando isto não.

Comment: Abri agora no Chrome 70 e no Firefox 63 o link que eu comentei com seu código está funcionando normalmente. Ao clicar no elemento o input ganha foco e é logado "Executado" no console.

Comment: Inclusive acabei de pegar este mesmo código e para o evento de clique funcionar eu tenho que copiar o js, e colocar no console, ai eu posso voltar e clicar lá na lupa, você chegou a clicar na lupa?

Comment: Você chegou a abrir o link que eu coloquei no primeiro comentário?

Comment: A minha versão é:
Versão 71.0.3578.98 (Versão oficial) 64 bits

Comment: Sim, no jsfiddle, funciona, mas provavelmente porque não tem um icone do fontawesome, porém quando eu separei este dois código um em html e o outro em js tbm não funcionou, chegou a fazer um teste local na sua máquina?

Comment: Entendi, o problema é que o FontAwesome vai trocar o elemento por um SVG e o `onclick` que tinha lá não vai existir mais.

Comment: Alguma maneira para que isto ocorra da forma que imagino?

Comment: Não vou conseguir formular uma resposta agora, mas vou dar um conselho: Apaga esse seu javascript e substitui o `<div class="search">` por `<label class="search">`. Você está tentando simular o comportamento de um label, é mais fácil usar o label mesmo.

Comment: Pode deixar, vou corrigir isto, mas queria entender o porque eu colar o código no console, ele faz que funcione?

Comment: Você está atribuindo uma função auto-invocada  à variável onload. Essa função é disparada no momento de sua atribuição... Ou seja, ela executa antes mesmo do onload ser disparado. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_definition.asp

Comment: Ao colar no console, a página já carregou e você está atribuindo a variável novamente, fazendo com que ela seja invocada novamente... Pra corrigir basta remover os parenteses da função ao fim da função

Comment: Outra questão é o uso de arrow function, vai funcionar em pouquíssimos navegadores.

Comment: Na verdade arrow function já tem um suporte bem descente. [93.49% segundo o caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions)

Comment: Já fiz de tirar a função imediatista, e a situação permanece a mesma, não muda em nada, e como ela está dentro de um onload ele só executa após o o carregamento mesmo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Galera, achei uma forma de resolver, acabei incluindo o código inline mesmo:

```
<i class="fas fa-search" onclick="nomedafuncaoquetornaclicavel()"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente seria melhor você usar o método [`Element.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) para escutar eventos, os métodos `onevento` são antigos e permitem apenas um handler de evento no elemento.

Ex.:

```
let elemento = document.getElementById('meu-elemento')
elemento.onclick = minha_funcao
```

Ficaria:

```
let elemento = document.getElementById('meu-elemento')
elemento.addEventListener('click', minha_funcao)
```

Então, no seu caso você poderia usar:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    console.log("Página carregada");
});
```

Você também precisa entender que quando você usa [*Immediately Invoked Function Expression*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) a variável vai receber o resultado da função, e não uma função (que é o que se espera receber como um *handler* de eventos).

Ex.:

```js
let valor_1 = (function(){ return 'Função 1'; })()
let valor_2 = function(){ return 'Função 2'; }

console.log(valor_1)
console.log(valor_2)
console.log(valor_2())
```

Mesmo aplicando os conceitos anteriores você teria problemas, pois o script está usando o atributo [`defer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer). Você teria que escutar o evento [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) para que sua função execute depois do script ser executado.

---

Agora, o ponto principal é que você está criando um script que serve apenas para dar foco num input quando já existe um elemento que faz isso nativamente para você, o [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label).

```html
<label>
  <input type="search">
  Click
</label>
```